# add active class on <a> element when we click on to make menu as highlighted

Tags: jquery, html, css

in menu, when user click on item, i want to hightlight with class,

i have html like this :

```
<div id="menu_wrapper">
    <ul class="art-hmenu">
        <li id="home"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li id="ProjectList"><a href="ProjectList.aspx">Project List</a><ul>
            <li id="ProjectListsub1"><a href="subone.aspx">Sub One</a></li>
            <li id="ProjectListsub2"><a href="subtwo.aspx">Sub Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="ProjectChoices"><a href="">Project Choices</a><ul>
            <li id="ProjectChoicessub1"><a href="StudentChoices.aspx">Student Project Choices</a></li>
            <li id="ProjectChoicessub2"><a href="StaffChoices.aspx">Supervisor Project Choices</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="ProjectAllocationList"><a href="AllocationList.aspx">Project Allocation List</a></li>
        <li id="SubmitProposal"><a href="">Submit Proposal</a><ul>
            <li id="SubmitProposalsub1"><a href="submit.aspx">New Proposal</a></li>
            <li id="SubmitProposalsub2"><a href="reSubmit.aspx">Re-Submit Proposal</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="StaffRecords"><a href="StaffRecords.aspx">Staff Records</a><ul>
            <li id="Li1"><a href="addStaff.aspx">Add new Staff</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="StudentRecords"><a href="StudentRecords.aspx">Student Records</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when user click on `<a>` i want to add class ="active"

what i tired is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".art-hmenu>ul>li").on("click", "a", function (event) {
                debugger;
                $("#menu_wrapper>ul>li.active").removeClass("active");
                $("#menu_wrapper>ul>li>a.active").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        });
```

but i am not able to add class , on `<a>`

Comment: add class to the anchor or the li?

Comment: Well you should decide if it's your `li`or your `a` that should get the class. Apart from that your code seems ok...

Comment: Is clicking the links changing the page, or are you intercepting the click and using ajax to load the content?

Comment: i want to add class on <a>!

Comment: @vb1 I don't think your code has a meaning, although you can add a class active to the clicked li, the  browser will be redirected  to another page when clicked

Comment: if you click on lets say <li id="ProjectList"><a href="ProjectList.aspx">Project List</a><ul>, but onclick the page redirects to  ProjectList.aspx, then there is no meaning in adding a active class in the current page

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong: `$(".art-hmenu>ul>li").on(`

You should have `$("ul.art-hmenu>li").on(`

In your html `ul` element has class `.art-hmenu`, so you want to have `ul.art-hmenu`.

You might want to simplify your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.art-hmenu>li").on("click", "a", function (event) {
        debugger;
        $("#menu_wrapper .active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HmfuD/)**

If you are looking for just adding that class to the first `<a>` (not the submenu) consider [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HmfuD/1/)

Comment: Does it maintain the style after redirect?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli, well I don't know how rest of OPs code is. In the post the question is "how to add class to `<a>` element", if there is a redirect it will not keep the new class of course.

Comment: Great, You can't see the code but you can see the links, it is redirecting to new page.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli, OP can have a function loading content inside the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script: Forgot to mention this codes needs to be on your master page.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


       $('.art-hmenu li').removeClass("active"); // if you want to style the li
       $('.art-hmenu li a').removeClass("active"); // if you want to style a specific a
       var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace( /^.*\/([^/]*)/ , "$1");

       ///// Apply active class to selected page link
        $('.art-hmenu a').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pageTitle.toLocaleLowerCase())
                $(this).addClass('activ');// // if you want to style a specific a
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');// if you want to style the li
         });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i suggest is to add one eventlistener to the ul with class art-hmenu and listen to a click event on all anchor  tags 
and then just look inside ul of class art-hmenu for any element with class of active 
and remove the class 
and then add the class active to the clicked element like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".art-hmenu").on("click", "a", function (event) { 
    $(".art-hmenu .active").removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("li > a").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("active");

});

});
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained what your are happening and why your solutions works as the OP intended.

Answer (score 0):

Add Bootstrap CDN :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li id="parentMenuId"><a href="#parentMenu">Parent Menu</a></li>
        <li id="childMenuId"><a href="#childMenu">Child Menu</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="parentMenu">
        <center>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>parent menu</h1>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="childMenu">
        <center>
            <h1>child menu</h1>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#childMenu").hide();
    $("#parentMenuId").addClass("active");

    $("#parentMenuId").click(function() {
        $("#parentMenu").show();
        $("#childMenu").hide();
        $("#parentMenuId").addClass("active");
        $("#childMenuId").removeClass("active");
    });

    $("#childMenuId").click(function() {
        $("#parentMenu").hide();
        $("#childMenu").show();
        $("#parentMenuId").removeClass("active");
        $("#childMenuId").addClass("active");
    });
});
```