# How to make particular Li tag active on click on anchor tag inside of that li tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my Li tag active when particular anchor tag inside li tag is clicked.

This is my Code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled detail-sidemenu mrb15">
    <li>
        <a onclick="Display1()" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> ABC</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="Display2()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>PQR</a>
    </li>
</ul>

.detail-sidemenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #ed1b23;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Now i want to apply this hover class css on Li tag:

```
 function Display1()
    {
        //active ABC
    }

 function Display2()
    {
         //Active PQR and remove active from ABC
    }
```

Comment: Try `$('ul').on('click', 'a', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
    return false;
});` Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3tr0o0fz/)

Comment: @Tushar:Sorry but i cant change my function.

Comment: Then repeat the code. `function Display1(e) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(e).closest('a').addClass('active');
    return false;
}

function Display2(e) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(e).closest('a').addClass('active');
    return false;
}` Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3tr0o0fz/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `click event handler` to your `anchor` instead of writing inline function as below:

```js
$('.ach').on('click', function() {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.detail-sidemenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #ed1b23;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled detail-sidemenu mrb15">
  <li><a href="#" class="ach"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="ach"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>PQR</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Update**

```js
function Display1(ctrl) {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(ctrl).closest('li').addClass('active')
}

function Display2(ctrl) {
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(ctrl).closest('li').addClass('active')
}
```

```css
.detail-sidemenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #ed1b23;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled detail-sidemenu mrb15">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Display1(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Display2(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>PQR</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Pass the control clicked to your `function` and access it in function accordingly

Comment: Sorry to say but i cant change my function

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To make particular `<li>` tag active or inactive refer this answer on stackoverflow.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034503/add-active-class-on-a-element-when-we-click-on-to-make-menu-as-highlighted/44354222#44354222)